# Reading a Parquet file whose Thrift schema has changed

Tags: thrift, parquet

I want to create Parquet files whose records are Thrift structs, and all the fields are `optional`.

Let's say I create a file `my_file.parquet` whose fields are `struct Bar { ... }`. Now, let's say I change `Bar` by deleting one field and adding another. What will happen when I try to read `my_file.parquet` using the updated `Bar` schema?

I'm assuming that Parquet would just skip the field that was removed from `Bar` when reading it?
If I try to read in the field that was added, would I just get `null`?

Any help would be appreciated. I cannot find this in the documentation. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The following is what Thrift does, so it is not specific to Parquet.

1. If it is optional (or "default"), then removing the field should not impose any issues. The content is skipped and ignored when the data are deserialized.
2. Same with adding a new optional field. It is optional, it is not in the old data, so according to the expectations we get an unset field after deserializing.
3. Best practices say, you should not remove the field, but **comment** it out. This prevents you and other people from accidentally reusing an outdated field ID later on. Which is a bad thing.
4. While we're at it: Think twice before you make anything `required`. Because `required` is forever.

Highly recommended lecture with some more in-depth explanations regarding that topic: [Diwaker Gupta's great "Missing Guide"](https://diwakergupta.github.io/thrift-missing-guide/)